# Is there an example of a docker-compose.yml that mounts persistent storage on AWS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I'd like to deploy a docker-compose.yml file to AWS Fargate with access to persistent storage. The official documentation includes a [Fargate tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-fargate.html) that defines a task with docker compose, but without persistent storage, while a separate [tutorial on how to mount an EFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/tutorial-efs-volumes.html) defines a task with json, but without a corresponding example in docker compose. Essentially, I'm looking to do what the second tutorial does with the tools from the first tutorial.

The most relevant question/answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403309/how-can-i-mount-an-efs-share-to-aws-fargate) provide further examples that mount EFS persistent storage in Fargate, but in json format. I'm committed to docker-compose in anticipation of Docker's integration with ECS ([currently in beta](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/ecs-integration/)), but am otherwise open to suggestions.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @MohamedSaleh No, not yet. At the time I wrote the question, the feature had just been released, and I decided to set it aside untill it was better documented. Sorry I can't help :(

Comment: no problem, thanks for your response