# AWS - Fargate - Adding EFS to Container - From AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I am trying to mount a persistent storage in a Fargate container.

- I have set up an `EFS` file system.
- I have set up an `ECS` Cluster.
- `EFS` and `ECS` share one subnet.
- When I try to create a task definition, I choose `Fargate` and then on `Add container`. I scroll down to `Storage and Logging` and cannot choose the `EFS` file system in `Mount points`. I cannot choose anything here, the only choice I have is: `<None>`

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403309/how-can-i-mount-an-efs-share-to-aws-fargate) suggests it is possible, but here it was answered using the AWS Cli Application. I wonder if I cannot just do it from the AWS Console (which is the web interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can setup `Mount point` in your Container definition, you have to setup `Volume` in your Task definition:

[image]

Comment: Oh my... That's outside. In the task definition, not inside the `Add container`. Do you know how much time this just ate. Thank you so very much!

Comment: @TheCommoner282 Yes, its not very intuitive. But glad it worked out:-)